# How to update css style from one page to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two pages: index.php and app.php

on first page (index.php) are placed elements for which I want to change css style value like font size. so on first page is located: `.options-parameters-input`element.

on the second page (app.php) is my options panel with inputs where i can input font size value for the desired element. in this case input is textarea `#heretype`

please see the code:

```
<div id="one">
<div class="options-parameters-input">
This is testing
</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Type font size</td>
    <td><textarea id="heretype"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>


$("#heretype").on("keyup",both);

function both(){
$(".options-parameters-input").css("fontSize", this.value + "px");
}
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/106/

My problem is how to transfer new css style value from one page (app.php) to another (index.php) ? because inputs are located in app.php page while desired elements are in index.php.

I hope you can help me

Thank you

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535660/how-to-pass-value-one-page-to-another-page-using-html

Comment: If both pages have `<link href='path/to/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>` then you could try editing the stylesheet programmatically which should affect any page linked to it, but each page would need to refresh in order to repaint styles.

Comment: I do not know if this helps or not, but app.php opens inside index.php, both pages are open.

Comment: if that is the case then you can have a single css included in index.php, that will do

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve **two ways**:

**Server side:**
   You can stored the value in **database(permanent)**. Then next page you can apply in css.

**Client side:**
    You can stored the value in **query parameter, cookie or local storage(temporary)**. Then next page you can apply in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update css of one page using javascript code from another page. Although what you could do is have an identifier to be shared between the pages. That could be lets say a url param saying **index.php?fontsize=10** and **app.php?fontsize=10**.

Then you can get the value of the param `fontsize` in your code on either pages and set it to the desired value and pass it around using javaScript.

You can have a default value for the fontsize at starting of the app or have a check saying if param `fontsize` exists or not in your javaScript code.

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873011/getting-value-from-radio-button-using-javascript/30873331#30873331) of mine.

Alternatively you can make use of **localStorage** -> [Window.localStorage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example) or **cookies** -> [Document.cookie()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

I would suggest going by either the URL param method or setting a localStorage object `fontSize` and update it whenever needed if you don't want to go with server side code and push the value of fontsize in db.

Answer (score 0):

As James Monger said, this isn't directly possible. However you can save the changes via PHP (to session or to database). Then when the user opens `index.php` a different `<style>...</style>` will be generated based on the saved setting. The setting can be saved by using a form or an ajax call (more complicated).

You can also write to a cookie directly from JavaScript and read it on another page